# php convert single quote to double quote for line break character

Tags: php, newline

I have a string coming from a language file containing strings with the text in the current language.

```
$str = 'blabla\n\nmore blabla';
```

$str is going to be used in an textarea where the \n must be a linebreak
If I place it inside double quotes this works.

The problem is that $str will always be in single quotes. I've been Googling and searching this site. There are many similar questions, but I didn't manage to find a solution.

How can I convert my single-quoted string (with a literal "\n") to a doublequoted string (where "\n" is converted to a linebreak)?

Comment: Here's a thread which answers your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309731/interpret-escape-characters-in-single-quoted-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$str = str_replace('\n', "\n", $str);

Comment: Just perfect. Thanks!