# "/e modifier is deprecated while calling preg_replace() with Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, preg-replace, symfony-1.4, deprecation-warning

Anyone know what is this error?

> Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\sfprojects\jobeet\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\response\sfWebResponse.class.php on line 409

I'm using **xampp 1.8.3** and **symfony 1.4**.

Comment: Please open said file and look up line 409. If you don't know what it means, post it here.

Comment: `return preg_replace('/\-(.)/e', "'-'.strtoupper('\\1')", strtr(ucfirst(strtolower($name)), '_', '-'));` this is at line 409.

Comment: Ok, the problem is the `e` in `'/\-(.)/e'`. You can try simply removing it, but that might break functionality. If you want to fix it properly, read this http://de.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php (PREG_REPLACE_EVAL). Other than that, your only options are turning off warnings, as this is apparently still working properly, or just downgrade PHP to 5.4, which still supports this feature.

Comment: Thank you @MrTweek. I'll do it.

Comment: It says `Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead`. can you translate it that line 409 for for me with the valid function it says (`preg_replace_callback()`). Thank you

Comment: Hello, symfony 1.4 isn't compatible with PHP 5.5. That's why you get this error. What I can suggest, is to use test our fork of symfony 1.4 that is compatible with PHP 5.5 it also add the DIC. Have a look: https://github.com/LExpress/symfony1

Answer (score 6):

In myproject/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/response/sfWebResponse.class.php on line 409

```
  protected function normalizeHeaderName($name)
  {
    // return preg_replace('/\-(.)/e', "'-'.strtoupper('\\1')", strtr(ucfirst(strtolower($name)), '_', '-'));    

    return preg_replace_callback(
                  '/\-(.)/', 
                  function ($matches) {
                    return '-'.strtoupper($matches[1]);
                  }, 
                  strtr(ucfirst(strtolower($name)), '_', '-')
        );
  }
```

FIX for pregtr method in /lib/vendor/symfony/lib/util/sfToolkit.class.php on line 360

```
public static function pregtr($search, $replacePairs){
  // return preg_replace(array_keys($replacePairs), array_values($replacePairs), $search);
  foreach($replacePairs as $pattern => $replacement)
  {
    if (preg_match('/(.*)e$/', $pattern, $matches))
    {
      $pattern = $matches[1];
      $search = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($matches) use ($replacement) {
        preg_match("/('::'\.)?([a-z]*)\('\\\\([0-9]{1})'\)/", $replacement, $match);
        return ($match[1]==''?'':'::').call_user_func($match[2], $matches[$match[3]]);
      }, $search);
    }
    else
    {
      $search = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $search);
    }
  }
  return $search;
}
```

I've combined two answers from duplicate thread [Symfony 1.4 using deprecated functions in php 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18077276/symfony-1-4-using-deprecated-functions-in-php-5-5) answered by [mika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1686492/mika) and [xtech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3432359/xtech) (up-vote them please)

It also affects /lib/form/addon/sfFormObject.class.php on line 281

```
  protected function camelize($text)
  {
    //return preg_replace(array('#/(.?)#e', '/(^|_|-)+(.)/e'), array("'::'.strtoupper('\\1')", "strtoupper('\\2')"), $text); //ORIGINAL
    return strtr(ucwords(strtr($text, array('/' => ':: ', '_' => ' ', '-' => ' '))), array(' ' => ''));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Found this:

http://blog.jakoubek.cz/symfony-1-4-deprecated-e-modifier

Tested, all changes look good

Answer (score 0):

as this function is called in several files in sf 1.4, here are all changes that i made in my projects (based on different sources, including sf 1.4 forks):

```
lib/vendor/symfony/lib/command/sfCommandManager.class.php
    @@ -108,7 +108,9 @@ class sfCommandManager
         else if (!is_array($arguments))
         {
           // hack to split arguments with spaces : --test="with some spaces"
    -      $arguments = preg_replace('/(\'|")(.+?)\\1/e', "str_replace(' ', '=PLACEHOLDER=', '\\2')", $arguments);
    +      $arguments = preg_replace_callback('/(\'|")(.+?)\\1/', function ($match) {
    +        return str_replace(' ', '=PLACEHOLDER=', $match[2]);
    +      }, $arguments);
           $arguments = preg_split('/\s+/', $arguments);
           $arguments = str_replace('=PLACEHOLDER=', ' ', $arguments);
         }

lib/vendor/symfony/lib/form/addon/sfFormObject.class.php
@@ -278,6 +278,6 @@ abstract class sfFormObject extends BaseForm

   protected function camelize($text)
   {
-    return preg_replace(array('#/(.?)#e', '/(^|_|-)+(.)/e'), array("'::'.strtoupper('\\1')", "strtoupper('\\2')"), $text);
+    return strtr(ucwords(strtr($text, array('/' => ':: ', '_' => ' ', '-' => ' '))), array(' ' => ''));
   }

lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/form/sfFormFilterDoctrine.class.php
@@ -323,7 +323,7 @@ abstract class sfFormFilterDoctrine extends sfFormFilter

   protected function camelize($text)
   {
-    return sfToolkit::pregtr($text, array('#/(.?)#e' => "'::'.strtoupper('\\1')", '/(^|_|-)+(.)/e' => "strtoupper('\\2')"));
+    return strtr(ucwords(strtr($text, array('/' => ':: ', '_' => ' ', '-' => ' '))), array(' ' => ''));
   }

lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/form/sfFormFilterPropel.class.php
@@ -263,6 +263,6 @@ abstract class sfFormFilterPropel extends sfFormFilter

   protected function camelize($text)
   {
-    return sfToolkit::pregtr($text, array('#/(.?)#e' => "'::'.strtoupper('\\1')", '/(^|_|-)+(.)/e' => "strtoupper('\\2')"));
+    return strtr(ucwords(strtr($text, array('/' => ':: ', '_' => ' ', '-' => ' '))), array(' ' => ''));
   }


lib/vendor/symfony/lib/response/sfWebResponse.class.php
@@ -406,7 +406,7 @@ class sfWebResponse extends sfResponse

   protected function normalizeHeaderName($name)
   {
-    return preg_replace('/\-(.)/e', "'-'.strtoupper('\\1')", strtr(ucfirst(strtolower($name)), '_', '-'));
+    return strtr(ucwords(strtr(strtolower($name), array('_' => ' ', '-' => ' '))), array(' ' => '-'));
   }


lib/vendor/symfony/lib/util/sfInflector.class.php
@@ -27,11 +27,7 @@ class sfInflector

   public static function camelize($lower_case_and_underscored_word)
   {
-    $tmp = $lower_case_and_underscored_word;
-    $tmp = sfToolkit::pregtr($tmp, array('#/(.?)#e'    => "'::'.strtoupper('\\1')",
-                                         '/(^|_|-)+(.)/e' => "strtoupper('\\2')"));
-
-    return $tmp;
+    return strtr(ucwords(strtr($lower_case_and_underscored_word, array('/' => ':: ', '_' => ' ', '-' => ' '))), array(' ' => ''));
   }
```

beside, here is the fix for the E_NOTICE lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php:

```
lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Query/Abstract.php
@@ -1149,7 +1149,16 @@ abstract class Doctrine_Query_Abstract
         $copy->free();

         if ($componentsBefore !== $componentsAfter) {
-            return array_diff($componentsAfter, $componentsBefore);
+            $diff = array();
+
+                       foreach($componentsAfter as $key => $val) {
+                               if(!isset($componentsBefore[$key])) {
+                                       $diff[$key] = $val;
+                               } elseif(is_array($componentsBefore[$key]) && !is_array($val)) {
+                                       $diff[$key] = $val;
+                               }
+                       }
+                       return $diff;
         } else {
             return $componentsAfter;
         }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can unset the E_DEPRECATED flag in every application settings.yml :

```
dev:
  .settings:
     error_reporting:  <?php echo ((E_ALL | E_STRICT) ^ E_DEPRECATED)."\n" ?>
```

Comment: This is a bad solution as I've already down voted in duplicate thread, as it only hides the problem and not fixes it. (C.O.) Hopefully Symfony 1.4.21 will fix those issues.