# PHP Warning: Missing argument 1 for sfOutputEscaperGetterDecorator::get(), called in

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm looking for a solution for one of my warnings.

System information:

- OS: FreeBSD
- Engine: nginx+php-fpm
- CMS: Symfony 1.4

The problem is when I try to list the data on backend Symfony Home I get the following error and data cannot be display instead raw data (link exp. to user's account) but not for all where nothing to display.

> [error] 7716#100111: *1288 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for sfOutputEscaperGetterDecorator::get(), called in /data/bin/cache/backend/prod/modules/autoSfGuardUser/templates/_list_td_tabular.php on line 2 and defined in /data/bin/lib/symfony/escaper/sfOutputEscaperGetterDecorator.class.php on line 45
>   PHP message: PHP Warning:  array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer in /data/bin/lib/symfony/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php on line 1357

File: /data/bin/lib/symfony/escaper/sfOutputEscaperGetterDecorator.class.php

```
    <?php

    /*
     * This file is part of the symfony package.
     * (c) 2004-2006 Fabien Potencier <fabien.potencier@symfony-project.com>
     *
     * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
     * file that was distributed with this source code.
     */

    /**
     * Abstract output escaping decorator class for "getter" objects.
     *
     * @see        sfOutputEscaper
     * @package    symfony
     * @subpackage view
     * @author     Mike Squire <mike@somosis.co.uk>
     * @version    SVN: $Id: sfOutputEscaperGetterDecorator.class.php 9047 2008-05-19 08:43:05Z FabianLange $
     */
    abstract class sfOutputEscaperGetterDecorator extends sfOutputEscaper
    {
      /**
       * Returns the raw, unescaped value associated with the key supplied.
       *
       * The key might be an index into an array or a value to be passed to the
       * decorated object's get() method.
       *
       * @param  string $key  The key to retrieve
       *
       * @return mixed The value
       */
      public abstract function getRaw($key);

      /**
       * Returns the escaped value associated with the key supplied.
       *
       * Typically (using this implementation) the raw value is obtained using the
       * {@link getRaw()} method, escaped and the result returned.
       *
       * @param  string $key             The key to retrieve
       * @param  string $escapingMethod  The escaping method (a PHP function) to use
       *
       * @return mixed The escaped value
       */
      public function get($key, $escapingMethod = null)
      {
        if (!$escapingMethod)
        {
          $escapingMethod = $this->escapingMethod;
        }

        return sfOutputEscaper::escape($escapingMethod, $this->getRaw($key));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I've found the problem and the solution.
The problem was with preg_replace and I've changed it like described here [Symfony 1.4 deprecated function in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091955/symfony-1-4-deprecated-function-in-php/)

But It will not work until clean the symfony cache.
I've delete all (folders and files) in folder cache (/data/bin/cache).

P.S. Helpful was the link http://blog.jakoubek.cz/symfony-1-4-deprecated-e-modifier as well.