# PHP preg_replace: Deprecated

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have this Deprecated warning after switching my php to 5.5.8,

> Deprecated:  preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead in **C:\wamp\www...Curly.php** on
>   line **28**

This is the function in my class of `Curly`,

```
public function replace ($input, $options = array()) {

        return preg_replace("/\{{2}(([a-z\_]+\|.+)|([a-z\_]+))\}{2}/Ue",'$this->_replace("\\1",$options)',$input);
    }
```

so if I use `preg_replace_callback` instead,

```
return preg_replace_callback("/\{{2}(([a-z\_]+\|.+)|([a-z\_]+))\}{2}/Ue",'$this->_replace("\\1",$options)',$input);
```

Then I get this error,

> **Warning**:  preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2,
>   '$this->_replace("\1",$options)', to be a valid callback
>   in **C:\wamp\www...Curly.php** on line **28**

Any ideas how can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

```
class Curly extends CoreModel
{
    // Set the property/ variable of this class
    public $constant = null;

    /**
     * Extend the parent class property.
     */ 
    public function __construct($connection){

       // Extend parent's.
       parent::__construct($connection);
       $this->constant = new Constant($connection);
    }

    /**
     * Replace the curly in an input string
     * @param string $input
     * @return string
     */
    public function replace ($input, $options = array()) {

        //return preg_replace("/\{{2}([a-z]+\|.+)\}{2}/Ue",'$this->_replace("\\1")',$input);
        //return preg_replace("/\{{2}(([a-z\_]+\|.+)|([a-z\_]+))\}{2}/Ue",'$this->_replace("\\1",$options)',$input);
        return preg_replace_callback(
            "/\{\{([a-z_]+(?:\|.+)?)\}\}/U",
            function($m) { return $this->_replace($m[1], $options); }, 
            $input
        );
    }

    /**
     * Run the replacement code on a given macro string
     * @param string $input
     * @return string
     */
    private function _replace ($input,$options) {

        // Set local vars.
        $defaults = array();

        // Call internal method to process the array.
        $array = parent::arrayMergeValues($defaults,$options);
        //print_r($array);

        // Convert array to object.
        $property = parent::arrayToObject($array);

        // type-checking comparison operator is necessary.
        if (strpos($input, '|') !== false) { 

            //VERTICAL SIGN FOUND
            list ($name,$params) = explode("|",$input);

            if (method_exists($this,$name)) {
                return $this->$name($params);
            }
            throw new Exception ("Unrecognised macro: {$name}.",500);

        } else {

            // Get the input string and request the data from constant table.
            $value = $this->constant->getRow($input)->value;

            // If there is a value returned from the contstant table.
            if($value !== null) { 

                // Return the what is returned from the the constant table.
                return $value;

            } else if(isset($property->$input)) { // If there is a customised value from the developer.

                // Return what is customised by the developer.
                return $property->$input;

            } else { // Nothing is found.

                // Return what is from the input.
                return "{{{$input}}}"; 

            }

        }   
    }

    /**
     * Replaces a YouTube curly
     * @param string $params
     * @return string
     */
    private function youtube ($params) {

        parse_str($params);

        // set defaults
        if (!isset($id)) { $id = "ykwqXuMPsoc"; }
        if (!isset($width)) { $width = 560; }
        if (!isset($height)) { $height = 315; }

        // output the final HTML
        return "<iframe width=\"{$width}\" height=\"{$height}\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$id}\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the examples in the [documentation](http://uk3.php.net/preg_replace_callback) the second argument has to be a function, not a string.

Comment: My explanation in this previous answer might also be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454220/replace-preg-replace-e-modifier-with-preg-replace-callback/15454454#15454454

Comment: In fact I think this is effectively a duplicate of that question, since the basic usage remains the same.

Comment: THanks IMSop, I tried that answer already, but I get error and the replacement does not happen at all.

Comment: @tealou Then please show the code you wrote based on that answer, and the error you got

Comment: Hi IMSoP, please see my entire code in my edit above. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
public function replace ($input, $options = array()) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "/\{\{([a-z_]+(?:\|.+)?)\}\}/U",
        function($m) use($options) { return $this->_replace($m[1], $options); }, 
        $input
    );
}
```

Comment: I like Anonymous functions :)

Comment: Your anonymous function doesn't actually execute the replacement, it will just insert some PHP code into the middle of the string.

Comment: @IMSoP: Yes it will. May be I'm wrong but I guess it is what the OP wants.

Comment: The deprecated `/e` modifier makes preg_replace `eval()` its argument. See my answer to a similar question linked above (probably similar enough to consider duplicate).

Comment: @IMSoP: OK, I see. I've added an alternative in my answer.

Comment: There's no ambiguity in the question, the old code will execute `$this->_replace`. Your first suggestion is wrong, and wouldn't need a callback at all anyway. Your second suggestion is right, except that you've missed the _callback from the function name.

Comment: thanks M42 but it doesn't actually execute the replacement... :(

Comment: I get this error, `preg_replace_callback(): Modifier /e cannot be used with replacement callback in...`

Comment: @tealou: Remove the `/e` as in my answer.

Comment: Hi M42, I removed /e from the answer then I get a new error, `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: options in <b>C:\wamp\www\...Curly.php</b> on line <b>33</b><br />`

Comment: @tealou: You have to add `use($options)` when calling the callback. See my edit.

Answer (score -2):

Otherwise with **call_user_func_array**:

```
return preg_replace_callback(
    // RegExpr
    "/\{{2}(([a-z\_]+\|.+)|([a-z\_]+))\}{2}/Ue",

    // Callback
    array($this, '_replace'),

    // Data
    $input
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what call_user_func_array has to do with anything. This code will also fail unless the _replace function is modified, as it is expecting a single string, but will be given all the matches from the regex as an array.

Comment: `call_user_func_array` will be called at this point.

Comment: No, it won't. That's just the standard way of representing an object callback in PHP. The "array" in call_user_func_array refers not to the type of callback but the arguments it's given, which are pulled from an array you provide as though you had listed them as separate parameters. Nothing like that is happening here.