# Error with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, php-7

I have a code like this. I think it just about PHP5/PHP7 compatiable problem

```
 function EncodeQ ($str, $position = 'text') {
    $encoded = preg_replace("[\r\n]", '', $str);
    switch (strtolower($position)) {
      case 'phrase':
        $encoded = preg_replace("/([^A-Za-z0-9!*+\/ -])/e", "'='.sprintf('%02X', ord('\\1'))", $encoded);
        break;
      case 'comment':
        $encoded = preg_replace("/([\(\)\"])/e", "'='.sprintf('%02X', ord('\\1'))", $encoded);
      case 'text':
      default:
        $encoded = preg_replace('/([\000-\011\013\014\016-\037\075\077\137\177-\377])/e',
              "'='.sprintf('%02X', ord('\\1'))", $encoded);
        break;
    }

    $encoded = str_replace(' ', '_', $encoded);

    return $encoded;
  }
```

Please help me to fix the code, the error is following

> preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Comment: I think this thread answers to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454220/replace-preg-replace-e-modifier-with-preg-replace-callback

Comment: There another question, but I cannot get from the above-mentioned post

$text = preg_replace("#\[tex\](.*?)\[/tex\]#sie","'<img src=\'http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\1\' border=\'0\' align=\'absmiddle\' alt=\'\\1\'></img>'", $text);

How should I do?