# Getting error: Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\'

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have found this question asked already but my code is so different from the others that I cannot seem to figure out how to apply what I found to my line of code in order to get it to work.  I have tried adding # into the second line after the first set of quotes but cant figure out where the ending # should go or if that's even actually what I should be doing.  Here is the code that is throwing the error.  Also, not sure if this matters but this was originally an ereg_replace that I am turning to preg_replace since ere was depreciated.

```
echo preg_replace( 
    "\"><a [\?a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\:\"\=\_ >]+</a>([\t\n]+)<ul"," haschildren\\0",
```

The error I am seeing on the front end is:

> Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\'

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See this for your current error message: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20705399/3933332 and see this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15454220/3933332 for the converting of `ereg_replace()` to `preg_replace()`. (Yes you are on the right path by adding delimiters to your regex. The links should help you to get it to work; Otherwise update the question with the new/current code)

Comment: Did you mean: `preg_replace("/\"><a [\?a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\:\"\=\_ >]+<\/a>([\t\n]+)<ul/", " haschildren\\0", $something);`?

Comment: Yes Edvin, that was it!  I was not placing the delimiter in the second <\/a> area.  I was only focusing on the first part.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this, though.