# preg_replace passing the matched group to a function weired result

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have the following `preg_replace` **not** [`preg_replace_callback`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454220/replace-preg-replace-e-modifier-with-preg-replace-callback) which uses **arrays** for search patterns and replacement not only a single value and it works fine:

```
preg_replace(['/\{/','/\}/','/"(.*?)"/'],['<span class=\'olive\'>{','}</span>','<span class=\'olive\'>${0}</span>'],FoxText::insertBr($model->TafseerText));
```

However, when I try to pass `${0}` to function something like:

```
preg_replace(['/\{/','/\}/','/"(.*?)"/'],['<span class=\'olive\'>{','}</span>',FoxText::pattern2VerseId("\$0")],FoxText::insertBr($model->TafseerText));
```

In the `FoxText::pattern2VerseId` function I try `print_r` as follows:

```
public static function pattern2VerseId($txt, $pattern = '/\(((\d+)-(\w+))\)/u')
 {
  $parts = array_map('trim',explode('-', $txt));
  print_r(explode('-', $parts[0]));
  return $parts[0].'  *'.$parts[0].'|';
 }
```

It prints `Array ( [0] => $0 )` while the return value is matched string from the previous call!

In other words, how could it able to return `$parts[0]` as a string and It could not able to explode this string. Or how could I pass the value correctly to the function to be processed there?

By the way, the string is something like `(125-Verse)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace preg\_replace() e modifier with preg\_replace\_callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454220/replace-preg-replace-e-modifier-with-preg-replace-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have PHP < 7. i.e there is no [preg_replace_callback_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback-array.php), the only solution that I have able to use is replacing the first pattern(s) using `preg_replace` then passing the output to one `preg_replace_callback`

```
$p = preg_replace(['/\{/','/«/','/\(/','/\}/','/»/','/\)/','/"(.*?)"/'],['<span class=\'olive\'>{','<span class=\'olive\'>«','<span class=\'olive\'>(','}</span>','»</span>',')</span>','<span class=\'olive\'>${0}</span>'],FoxText::insertBr($model->TafseerText));
$callback = function($m){return FoxText::pattern2VerseId($m);}; 
echo preg_replace_callback('/\(((\d+)-(\w+))\)/u', $callback, $p);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you call the function `pattern2VerseId` you call it with the **string** `$0`. And since string `$0` doesn't contain any hyphen, the `explode` just returns an array with single element containing the string.

`explode('-', '$0') // will return Array([0] => $0)`

By `"\$0"` are you actually trying to get the first part of the matched regex, i.e. 125 in this case? Because you're not doing it right.

Comment: what I mean by that is you think you're passing the matched part, but in fact you're just passing the string `$0`.