# Need help to replace preg_replace_callback in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

Need help to solve error like below,

```
preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in line 601
```

Got error in below code,

```
$string = preg_replace('~&#x0*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $string);
$string = preg_replace('~&#0*([0-9]+);~e', 'chr(\\1)', $string);
```

**AM tried like.**

```
$string =  preg_replace_callback('~&#x0*([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))',function ($match) {
return ($match[1]);
}, $string);
```

But still got error like these?

```
Requires argument 2, 'chr(hexdec(&quot;\1&quot;))'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace preg\_replace() e modifier with preg\_replace\_callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454220/replace-preg-replace-e-modifier-with-preg-replace-callback)

Comment: Am tired but not working.

Comment: Where is the code where you *tried that*? Where have you tried to pass the anonymous function as the second argument?

Comment: Don't modify [framework files](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/v2.0.3/system/core/Security.php#L471) by hand; just update it to a recent version.

Comment: Please check my above code got error like Requires argument 2, 'chr(hexdec(&quot;\1&quot;))'

Comment: According to Narf's link, your code belongs to an alternative to `html_entity_decode()` written to workaround a PHP/4 bug. Unless you're still using PHP/4 (with is more than dated) there's no reason to avoid the native function.

Answer (score 2):

As the error indicates, the `e` modifier is no longer supported in your PHP version.

The `preg_replace_callback` equivalent would look like this:

```
$string = preg_replace_callback('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~i', function ($m) {
    return chr(hexdec($m[1]));
}, $string);
```

NB: The `0*` in your regex is not needed, as zeroes are captured by the pattern that follows that, and it does not bother to have those zeroes captured in the capture group.

**BUT**, as you are on a PHP version equal or higher than 5.5 (as [those versions produce the error](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)), you can rely on `html_entity_decode`:

```
$string = html_entity_decode($string);
```