# WP-lightbox Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Tags: php, wordpress, deprecated

My plugin wp-lightbox evolution is showing me an error

> Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use
>   preg_replace_callback instead

And when I replace that with `preg_replace_callback` I'm getting an error:

> Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2,
>   'stripslashes(strstr("\1\3", "class=") ? "\0" : "")', to be a valid callback

Any Help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace preg\_replace() e modifier with preg\_replace\_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454220/replace-preg-replace-e-modifier-with-preg-replace-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`preg_replace` with the `/e` modifier used to accept the PHP code as string.

`preg_replace_callback` accepts a [callable](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). The function that `preg_replace_callback` should accept an array of matches and return the string to be used as a replacement.

If you don’t use this code anywhere else, it makes sense to use an anonymous function, like this:

```
preg_replace_callback(YOUR_PATTERN_HERE, function ($matches) {
  return stripslashes(
    strstr($matches[1] . $matches[3], "class=")
      ? $matches[0]
      : "");
}, YOUR_STRING_TO_BE_CHANGED_HERE);
```

See a question [Replace preg_replace() e modifier with preg_replace_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454220/replace-preg-replace-e-modifier-with-preg-replace-callback) for more info.