# In PHP7 how Replace thes code from preg_replace() to preg_replace_callback()

Tags: php-7, preg-replace-callback

how Replace thes code from preg_replace() to preg_replace_callback() ?

```
$search_array   =   array();
$replace_array  =   array();

$search_array[]     =   '~\{\$([^[<].*?)\[\'([^[<].*?)\'\]\[\'([^[<].*?)\'\]\}~';
$replace_array[]    =   '<?php echo $DHGS->_CONF[\'template\'][\'\\1\'][\'\\2\'][\'\\3\']; ?>';

$search_array[]     =   '~\{\$([^[<].*?)\[([^[<].*?)\]\[([^[<].*?)\]\}~';
$replace_array[]    =   '<?php echo $DHGS->_CONF[\'template\'][\'\\1\'][\'\\2\'][\'\\3\']; ?>';

$search_array[]     =   '~\{\$([^[<].*?)\[\'([^[<].*?)\'\]\}~';
$replace_array[]    =   '<?php echo $DHGS->_CONF[\'template\'][\'\\1\'][\'\\2\']; ?>';

$search_array[]     =   '~\{\$([^[<].*?)\[([^[<].*?)\]\}~';
$replace_array[]    =   '<?php echo $DHGS->_CONF[\'template\'][\'\\1\'][\'\\2\']; ?>';

$search_array[]     =   '~\{\$([^[<].*?)\}~';
$replace_array[]    =   '<?php echo $DHGS->_CONF[\'template\'][\'\\1\']; ?>';

$search_array[]     =   '~\{template}([^[<].*?){/template}~';
$replace_array[]    =   '<?php $this->display(\'\\1\'); ?>';

$search_array[]     =   '~\{include}([^[<].*?){/include}~';
$replace_array[]    =   '<?php include(\\1); ?>';

$search_array[]     =   '~\{info_row}([^[<].*?){/info_row}~';
$replace_array[]    =   '<?php $this->info_row(\'\\1\'); ?>';

$search_array[]     =   '~\{get_hook}([^[<].*?){/get_hook}~';
$replace_array[]    =   '<?php $this->get_hooks_template(\'\\1\'); ?>';

//////////
$string = preg_replace($search_array,$replace_array,$string);
```

The above code gives deprecated warning.

How do Convert from preg_replace to preg_replace_callback !
I tried converting but it was a complicated process ..

Comment: what is the deprecation warnings that you get? I had tried your code in php7.3 and did not get any warnings

Comment: does not work correctly in PHP Version 7.2.9

php error preg_replace() the /e modifier is deprecated use preg_replace_callback instead

Comment: I do not see any `/e` modifiers in your posted code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace preg\_replace() e modifier with preg\_replace\_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454220/replace-preg-replace-e-modifier-with-preg-replace-callback)

Comment: Forget the warning It is not as important
This code does not work well by preg_replace

Can you  change it to run on preg_replace_callback ?