# preg_replace vs preg_replace_callback

Tags: php

I'm trying to update the code for some very old plugins for a very old blog. I've fixed almost everything except this.

I get an error message that I must replace preg_replace with preg_replace_callback.

This is the code:

```
 $source_content = preg_replace($search.'e', "'"
                                   . $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
                                   . "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('\\0', \"\n\")) .'"
                                   . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter)
                                   . "'"
                                   , $source_content);
```

If I simply substitute preg_replace_callback for the preg_replace I get this error:

```
preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, ''{{php' . str_repeat(" ", substr_count('\0', " ")) .'}}'', to be a valid callback in
```

I'm neither a perl nor a php person. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454220/replace-preg-replace-e-modifier-with-preg-replace-callback) might help

Comment: beter you upgrade to latest smarty2 library it would solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading your smarty library to the latest smarty2 would solve your problem fix was there over 5 years now.

But This might help you :

```
$source_content = preg_replace_callback($search . 'e',
            function ($matches) {
                return "'"
                 . $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
                . "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('$matches[0]', \"\n\")) .'"
               . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter) . "'";
            },
    $source_content
 );
```

Here is the explanition and more examples :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php