# PHP regex - how to capitalize a specific string when found within another string using regex?

Tags: php

(This question is **not** a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15454220/replace-preg-replace-e-modifier-with-preg-replace-callback).)

How can I capitalize the string `llc` when found within another string, surrounded by word boundaries? In other words, I don't want to captilalize `llc` if it's in the middle of another word, such as `ballcap`, but only when it's by itself, either surrounded by spaces, end of string, etc. Such as `my big company, llc`.

I have the following line of PHP that worked fine in PHP 5.6, to capitalize the string `llc` whenever found within another string:

```
$foo = trim(preg_replace('/\bllc\b/ie', 'strtoupper("$0")', $str));
```

But in PHP 7.4 (and maybe all 7.x), that always returns empty string, regardless of what string is fed in for the value of `$str`.

I have tried using `preg_replace_callback` but can't seem to get the syntax right for my use case.

Example: `big company, llc` should become `big company, LLC`

Any idea how I can get this working in 7.4?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate?  It shows you exactly what to use instead of the `e` modifier.

Comment: what is the `e` modifier? The `e` at the end of the regex pattern?

Comment: Yes, the duplicate shows you how to use `preg_replace_callback` and a function to get the `0` match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e` modifier is deprecated, you should use `preg_replace_callback`
It runs a function with an array of all matches and uses return value as replacement

```
$foo = trim(preg_replace_callback('/\bllc\b/i', function($matches) {
    return strtoupper($matches[0]);
}, $str));
```