# php and special characters

Tags: php, post, escaping, special-characters, forms

In PHP, when I write

```
$string="\thello world\t"
echo trim($string);
```

this outputs `hello world`. However, when I enter the same string in a HTML form input field and post to the server, the behavior changes.

```
echo trim($_POST["string"];
```

The above code outputs `\thello world\t`

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `\t` inside of double quotes is an [escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) that is expanded to the literal tab character. However, when you type `\t` into an input field, it is posted as the literal characters `\t`.

In this example, this code.

```
echo trim($_POST["string"];
```

Is analogous to this code.

```
$string='\thello world\t'
echo trim($string);
```

Escape sequences are not expanded inside strings declared by single quotes.

If you need the functionality to expand the escape sequences from a submitted string, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309731/interpret-escape-characters-in-single-quoted-string) offers a few techniques.

Comment: So, any input that comes from GET or POST is special character-safe?

Comment: @Whiteley Not necessarily, a user can still submit any arbitrary data, even if the input does not allow it. Escape sequences however, will not be expanded. If you are only concerned that a user might submit leading/trailing whitespace, `trim` is sufficient.

Comment: in this case, trim only removes space character, not special characters like \n or \t, am I right?

Comment: @Whiteley Space and other whitespace characters yes. `\n`, `\t` etc will literally be the characters entered and not transformed into whitespace.

Comment: @alexander-omara Normally, I use preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string) on any input that is coming from $_POST to remove excess whitespace. I just want to able to keep if a user writes something "My name is newline(\n)". Based on your answer, I can continue to use this function and I don't need to worry about it right?

Comment: @alexander-omara Yes, but trim does not remove extra spaces inside the string (between individual words).

Comment: @Whiteley Right, if you want to strip internal whitespace, then your `preg_replace` solution is what you want.