# How can I get values coming out of MySQL to be interpreted by PHP as if they're encapsulated in double quotes, not single?

Tags: php, mysql, string

I have a lot of MySQL string content that has many instances of "\n" in it. I know that if I'm dealing with strings directly, the "\n" is only interpreted as a line break if I have double quotes around it. However, when the strings come out of the database, they're interpreted literally (the '\n' stays as is). Obviously I can do my own str_replace(), but is there a simple way to treat values from mySQL as if they were double-quote-enclosed strings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241748/php-convert-single-quoted-string-to-double-quoted

Comment: reads like the data is going in to the db incorrectly.

Comment: `stripcslashes()` does that (and a bit more). But you may still want to fix your prior database population woes.

Comment: The data is Markdown text being imported from CSV files where editors have used \n instead of line breaks as the line breaks are misinterpreted as some unknown character.

Answer (score 0):

While inserting string data in db I prefer to use addslashes() functions. With this my data is inserted correctly in MySQL format. Also when showing the data on front-end, I use stripslashes(). You can always refer PHP manual for more info on this functions.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data isn't being added to MySQL via PHP.